# How to get title of files associated to two objects from Salesforce in Talend ETL?

Tags: file, salesforce, talend

I have a talend job that contains two objects salesforce A and B .the object B is associated with object A (one to many),the join Model is 'inner join'.I'd like to get the title of files associated to object A and object B .
I use ContentDocumentink and tsetglobalvar to get the ids of object A and the ids of objects B.But the job show me only the title of files associated to object A not object B.

How can I establish this ?

Thank you ,

Khouloud

I try to use contentDocumentLink that's filter by linkedEntityId but it display to me only the files related to object A.

Comment: This is the soql qery that i use : 
`SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId ,
                    ContentDocument.title ,
                    ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.FileExtension, 
                    ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title
                     FROM ContentDocumentLink 
where (LinkedEntityId='"+(String)globalMap.get("OffreId")+"' or  LinkedEntityId='"+(String)globalMap.get("PosId")+"')
and ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.FileExtension!='zip'`